# JQuery UI DatePicker - How to manually open a datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can a manually open a datepicker for js code?

Comment: on which event do you want to manually open the the date picker??

Answer (score 26):

To show the datepicker associated to the input with id 'your_elem', you would use something like this:

```
jQuery('#your_elem').datepicker("show");
```

Comment: @Incredible see the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show You're probably having a typo or a mistake in your selector, check your console for errors ? And if still not working, post a new question here on SO

Comment: In my case the datepicker is a part of a Drupal module and your solution is giving me an error "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined". Maybe that is the difference. The selector is right since my solution posted as an answer works for me with the same selector.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#datepickerid').focus()` should do the trick.

Comment: This is a good idea. It almost solved my problem, hovewer I had to add another line: `$('#datepickerid').click();`

Answer (score 2):

for me, neither of the suggested solutions work.
the date picker opens, but then immediately it closes.
so I solved this by using:

```
setTimeout('$("#datepicker_element").focus();', 320);
```

hope this helps someone

Comment: Same for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (datepicker was a part of a Drupal module in this case) and for me worked this:

```
$('input.date').focus();
$('input.date').click();
```

It didn't work when only `$('input.date').click();` was used.

Answer (score 0):

Did work for me:

```
    setTimeout(function(){$("input#element_id").focus();}, 200);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
    $('#DatePicker').datepicker({
        duration: '',
        showTime: true,
        constrainInput: false,
        maxDate: '+1y',
        minDate: '-0d',
        defaultDate: ''
    });
});
```